# I need a C/C++ .DOCX reader API for reports printing (a .DOCX TO HTML converter instead would also be helpful)

Tags: c++, html, c, reporting, office

I have written a simple C++ application that can print reports if needed,

I am using HTML as my main reports viewer and printer,

Everything is working great until lot of users became asking if I can add .DOCX as a second option for reporting, where they can use their custom reports created using MS Word 2007 and later, containing like holes like @NAME@, @DOB@, ...etc so my app will do a search and replace later before print previewing these reports.

I need a C/C++ .DOCX reader API, or a .DOCX TO HTML converter instead because I am using HTML in the first place.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only full featured C++ library for MS Word document manipulation and conversion is [Aspose.Words For C++](https://products.aspose.com/words/cpp)